# getAccuracy in FusedLocationProviderClient Android always return value that minimum is 10.0

Tags: android, location, android-gps, fusedlocationproviderclient

why getAccuracy method in FusedLocationProviderClient always return value that minimum is 10.0 (never under 10) ?

```
mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
            mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
            mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
            mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
            mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(0);
            getFusedLocationProviderClient(getApplicationContext()).requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, new LocationCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                            // do work here
                            longFused=locationResult.getLastLocation().getLongitude();
                            latFused=locationResult.getLastLocation().getLatitude();
                            accFused=locationResult.getLastLocation().getAccuracy();
                            sendMessageToUI(longFused, latFused, accFused,locationResult.getLastLocation().getTime());

                }
            },
            Looper.myLooper());
```

with that code, I always got accFused never under 10.0,  anybody can help ?

Answer (score 0):

Because it isn't more accurate than that.  Fused is not the most accurate method (GPS is more accurate, but takes more battery) and even that has a couple of meters inaccuracy in the best case with consumer level hardware.